# fixing react-leaflet testing error: Cannot read property '_layerAdd' of null

Tags: jestjs, react-leaflet

I'm having some issues with the basic rendering tests from create-react-app and the `Polyline` component from react-leaflet. Whenever I try to add the `Polyline` as a child to my `Map`, I get the test error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property '_layerAdd' of null`. The map and polyline both still show in the browser just fine, but this test error is getting a little annoying.

Has anyone faced the same issue? If so, how did you resolve it?

I've seen a few similar questions asked, but no real answer yet for when using react-leaflet. I've tried tying the map rendering to `componentDidMount`, but without luck.

Here's my render for my map:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Map
        animate={this.state.animate}
        center={this.state.latlng}
        length={4}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        zoom={13}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={pathPoints[0]} />
        <Marker position={pathPoints[pathPoints.length - 1]} />
        <Polyline color="red" positions={pathPoints} />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

In fact, it has nothing to do with `react-leaflet` library. Leaflet [`Polyline`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#polyline) uses [`SVG` renderer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#svg) (by default) but [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) which comes with [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) test runner for  Create React App, does not support SVG to a full extent (in particular `createSVGRect` [is not supported](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/464)). That's basically the reason why the specified error occurs.

**How to configure Create React App to pass tests?**

It rather needs to be considered as a workaround but the idea is to extend JSDOM `SVGSVGElement` by introducing `createSVGRect` as an empty function. This technique will allow to emulate  SVG support in JSDOM in order to pass Jest tests for *vector overlays* such as Polygon

Under `src` directory create a file named `setupTests.js` and provide the following code:

```
var createElementNSOrig = global.document.createElementNS
global.document.createElementNS = function(namespaceURI, qualifiedName) {
  if (namespaceURI==='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' && qualifiedName==='svg'){
    var element = createElementNSOrig.apply(this,arguments)
    element.createSVGRect = function(){}; 
    return element;
  }
  return createElementNSOrig.apply(this,arguments)
}
```

Comment: I believe [this PR](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1371) may one day solve this problem.

Comment: I am still getting the error since that was merged, @ChrisPaul. However, I am using Vite, and the undefined error is `_leaflet_id`